# TensorFlow gradients w.r.t. intermediate results inside while_loop body

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I've implemented some recurrent models with TensorFlow using tf.scan and currently I'm trying to obtain the gradient of output loss w.r.t. states at each time step for research purpose.

The key process can be reduced to calculating the gradient w.r.t. intermediate values inside a while_loop body:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.InteractiveSession()

sequence = tf.constant([2, 3, 4, 5])
def body(t, previous_s):
  intermediate_s = previous_s * sequence[t]
  return t + 1, intermediate_s

t0, s0 = 0, 1
_, s4 = tf.while_loop(lambda t, _: t < sequence.shape[0], body, (t0, s0))
print('s4 =', s4.eval())
```

The output is

```
s4 = 120
```

and the intermediate results calculated during the while loop are

```
s1 = 2, s2 = 6, s3 = 24
```

So is there a way to access to those tensors so I can calculate the corresponding gradient using tf.gradient, say for `dS4/dS1`:

```
ds4_ds1 = tf.gradient(s4, s1)[0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a way to do that. Your best bet would be to unroll the loop and use a python while instead for that (which you probably already know).

Comment: I've done that using a roundabout way (calculate a Jacobian dS[t]/dS[t-1] in each time step and apply the chain rule outside the loop). Thank you anyway :D